# AWS R53 api via PrivateLink

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-route53, vpc, aws-private-link

Is there any valid way of reaching AWS Route53 APIs over PrivateLink ? My lambdas have to stay private, with no global network connectivity, but those also need to be able to execute Route53 api calls. Exhausted my ideas and would appreciate any brilliant ideas.

Comment: Unfortunately, Route53 does not support PrivateLink at this time https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/aws-services-privatelink-support.html

Comment: @MarkB Thanks for Your input. Any creative workarounds you could think of ?

Comment: You mention Route 53 APIs. Do you actually mean APIs or resolving hostnames via Route 53? If the first, what is the use case?

Comment: @JohnHanley my use case brought me to this question. When we onboard new customers we use the API to setup custom subdomains for them.

Comment: @DaveRager- If your use case or problem differs, post a new question. If you are using PrivateLink, I have not seen news of its support.